# how to prevent printing output of raw_input()?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using `password = raw_input()` to prompt for passwords so that I don't have to embed passwords in notebooks.

However, the notebook outputs the value entered in the prompt, and on one occasion I accidentally saved the output and shared it.

Is it possible to prevent the notebook from displaying the value entered?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getpass:

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass('Enter your password: ')
```